# Mongoose create a document if not found with specified fields, if found update an array in the document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I am facing a problem of creating a document if it does not exist, and if it exists, I want to update an array in the document.

For example, if I have

```
var courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code : { type: String },
    name : { type: String },
    dept : { type: String },
    instructors : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});

var Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

...
...
// This code should check if a course exists with a specified 'code' and 
// 'name' and , if it exist, I want to add req.body.instructor_id to
// instructor array in that document, else I want to create a document with
// the specified course, name(and dept) and with req.body.instructor_id as the only element in
// the instructors array

// So far I have this, but it is clearly wrong.


Course.findOneAndUpdate(
    {code: req.body.code, name: req.body.name},
    {$push: {instructors: req.user._id}},
    {upsert: true},
    function (err, course) {
        if (err)
            console.log("error " + err);
        else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(course, null, '\t'));
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter should be the whole object, not only instructors. For example:

```
function findOneAndUpdateCourse(req, callback){
    Course.findOneAndUpdate(
        {code: req.body.code, name: req.body.name},
        { 
          $setOnInsert: { code: req.body.code},
          $setOnInsert: { name: req.body.name},
          $push: {instructors: req.user._id}}
        },
        {upsert: true},
        function (err, course) {
            if (err)
                console.log("error " + err);
            else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(course, null, '\t'));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: But thats a problem. Say if course has more fields than only name and code. . say course also included a field 'dept' and I dont want to modify it in case updates, this approach is not feasible. I wouldnt be able to populate the course in its entirety before finding. I have updated the sample code in question to highlight this problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. I've edited my answer @Anoop. SetOnInsert will only update field when inserting.

Comment: I just changed my implementation a bit to get my problem solved, hence could not verify this. Thanks anyway. I will try this too and see how it works.